# remote_api SDK 1.9.27 won't connect to localhost

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I noticed this morning that using the remote_api in the most recent SDK generates 401 responses when connecting to localhost.

I have been using this same connection method for years now.

> python remote_api_shell.py -s localhost:8080

This now generates many 401 responses in the server console and then aborts the connection. By 401 responses I mean that when trying to connect to the locally running server, the remote_api_shell hits /_ah/remote_api with a GET request. This GET requests returns an http 401 response.

My environment is Python 2.7 using SDK 1.9.27.

I can connect to remote app engine instances just fine, it is only the connection to localhost that exhibits this behavior.

Has something changed? Do we need to do something differently?

Comment: Be more specific on the "responses" and your environment or this'll be closed as unclear.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510527/how-to-authenticate-google-appegine-python-remote-api-access

Comment: I'd try logging/capturing HTTP traffic to find out what the server doesn't like. Maybe the authentication mechanism has changed and/or you have a version mismatch.